# Finding Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let there be a matrix
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & 3 & 5 \\ 1 & 3 & 3 \\ 1 & 5 & 1
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Give an example for a vector how is not an Eigenvector (and not zero)

1. The straightforward way is to look for the Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues, is there a shorter way?
2. Can I row reduce the matrix to find the characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most non-zero vectors are not eigenvectors of this matrix.  For example, $(1,0,0)^T$ is not an eigenvector.

Row-reducing the matrix will change the characteristic polynomial. So no, you can't find the eigenvalues of this matrix by row-reducing it.

Comment: As for the eigenvector, should I look for linear combination of the matrix columns, how did you find $(1,0,0)^T$?

Comment: I guessed.  As I indicated, most guesses will be correct here.

Comment: and on any other matrix are they things that I should look for?

Comment: For similar problems: note that if $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ are all eigenvectors, then the matrix must be diagonal.  So, for any non-diagonal matrix, one of these will work.

Comment: If you have a diagonal matrix, then the eigenvalues/eigenvectors are obvious anyway.

Comment: so If I have a non-diagonal matrix, then the non eigenvalues/eigenvectors are obvious anyway not $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$?

Comment: I don't understand that sentence

Comment: Never mind, thanks a lot!